# Resource Allocating by SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have  a problem while allocating resources to different records,the issue is as following:

First table gathers data including `Product ID, Planned Amount`

Second table gathers data including `Material ID, Actual Amount Used, Inventory`.
(the relationship type between the two is one-to-many)

I wanna to mix the two tables in one query showing following details:

```
Product ID  Planned Amount Material ID Actual Amount Used Inventory Remained Inventory
1              10             5            20               250        250-(10*20)=50
2              5              5            5                50          50-(5*5)=25
3              1              5            10               25           25-(1*10)=15
```

How can I create above table through SQL in Access?

Comment: with what part of your current sql statement you have problem with?

Answer (score 0):

You say

> the relationship type between the two is one-to-many

but there does not appear to be a foreign key in the "materials" table to join to the "product" table.

Assuming the `ProductID` is available as a foreign key and the table names are `Product` and `Material`:

```
SELECT [Product].[Product ID]
    ,[Planned Amount]
    ,[Material ID]
    ,[Actual Amount Used]
    ,[Inventory]
    ,[Inventory]-([Planned Amount]*[Actual Amount Used]) AS [Remained Inventory]
FROM Product INNER JOIN Material 
    ON Product.ProductID = Material.ProductID
```

But I suspect there is more to your question as the `Material ID` is the same for all rows, does the calculation have to take in to account other products using inventory of the same material?